# rotate and center globe on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have this code:

```
    d3.json("world-countries.json", function(collection) {
      feature = svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(collection.features)
          .enter().append("svg:path")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill",
                "#ffffff"); })
          .on("mouseout", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill",
                "#000000"); })
          .on("click", click)
          .attr("d", clip);
```

then my 'click' function is

```
    function click() {
        var o1 = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
        var lat = o1[0]
        lon = o1[1];
        console.log([o1]);
        projection.origin([o1]);
        circle.origin([o1]);
        refresh();
    }
```

and here is the demo http://bl.ocks.org/2876083

when i click on the svg, the map disappears!

how would you make this so that, the globe rotates and centers on 'click' point?

Comment: ok, i found this http://bl.ocks.org/1392560 but the spinning of the globe tilts the axis, so the globe in effect spins clock-wise and the y-axis also turns. is there a way to make the globe animate just on one axis?

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted at
http://bl.ocks.org/johan/1392560

You can find:

```
function mousemove() {
    if (m0) {
        var m1 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY]
          , o1 = [o0[0] + (m0[0] - m1[0]) / 8, o0[1] + (m1[1] - m0[1]) / 8];
        projection.origin(o1);
        circle.origin(o1);
        refresh();
    }
}
```

You need to modify `o1`.

`event.pageX` is the horizontal mouse position (used to work out the horizontal change)

`event.pageY` is the vertical mouse position.

`o1` is the new midpoint of the map, as *[horizontal,vertical]*
It's calculated using the old map midpoint and the difference *(old - new)* in mouse position.

```
var m1 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY]
  , o1 = [o0[0] + (m0[0] - m1[0]) / 8, o0[1] + (m1[1] - m0[1]) / 8];
```